Locus of points of contact of tangents from $(-4,0)$ to the swelling parabola: $y^2=4ax$, a>0
Locus of points of contact of tangents from $(-4,0)$ to  the swelling circle $$x^2+y^2=a^2, 0<a<4 \cdots (1)$$  turns out to be another circle: $$x^2+4x+y^2=0\cdots (2)$$ whose end points of the diameter are $(0,0)$ and $(-4,0)$ and it cuts $(1)$ orthogonally.
The question here is: What is the locus of points of contact of tangents from $(-4,0)$ to the swelling parabola: $y^2=4ax, a>0?$

It's line $y=4$.

@Intelligenti pauca No, please, it is not.

Right, I had interchanged $x$ with $y$, sorry.

Let $P(-4,0)$ and the point of contact $T(h,k)$ on the parabola $y^2=4ax, a>0.$
The slope of PT is $m_{PT}=\frac{k}{h+4}$ and which can be equated to the solpe ($m=\frac{2a}{k}$) of tangent at $(h,k)$. We get $$\frac{k}{h+4}=\frac{2a}{k} \implies k^2=2ah+8a\implies 2ah=8a\implies h=4.$$
We have used $k^2=4ah$, $a$ gets eliminated
giving us the required locus as the line $$x=4.$$
